QuickOSM Python Error ; I don't find file history to remove it
I want to use QuickOSM. But, there are problem in Python error. I have tried to search history in file QuickOSM, but I can't find it. I don't know how to fix it.
There is said that :
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) 

File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS34~1.0\apps\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)


Hey @Yohana, welcome to GIS StackExchange. Would be good to get some more information. What version of QGIS are you using? What version of the plugin are you using? What are you doing with the plugin when you get the error?

What do you mean with "I have tried to search history in file QuickOSM". You must edit your question by adding more information.
